# Logarithm on infinite tensor products continuous?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Denote $V:=\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the Cartesian product $V^\infty:=\prod_{k=0}^\infty V^{\otimes k}$ together with its canonical projections $\pi_k : V^\infty\rightarrow V^{\otimes k}, (v_0, v_1, \ldots)\mapsto v_k$, where $V^0:=\mathbb{R}$ and each factor space $V^{\otimes k}$ is equipped with the usual (Euclidean) tensor norm $\|\cdot\|_k$ inherited from $V$.

Define the space

$$\tag{1}E \,:=\,\left\{v\in V^\infty \ \middle| \ \sum_{k\geq 0}\|\pi_k(v)\|_k\cdot\lambda^k<\infty, \ \forall\,\lambda>0\right\}$$

and endow it with the *locally convex topology* induced by the family of norms $\|v\|_\lambda:=\sum_{k\geq 0}\|\pi_k(v)\|_k\lambda^k$, $\lambda>0$.

For each $v\equiv(v_k)\in V^\infty$ with $v_0=1$, define the *(formal) logarithm* $\log(v)$ as

$$\tag{2} \log(v)\, := \, \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}(v-1)^{\otimes k}.$$

**Question:** Is it true that $v\mapsto\log(v)$ is continuous as a map from (the subspace) $E_1:=\{v\equiv(v_k)\in E\mid v_0=1\}$ to $E$?

Continuity w.r.t. the product topology on $E$ is trivial (as $\pi_k\circ\log$ is a polynomial for each $k\geq 0$), but the required case seems less clear. Any hints or references are appreciated.

Comment: what is the quantifier on $\lambda$ in the definition of $E$ ?

Comment: $\lambda$ ranges over all positive scalars. (The dot $\cdot$ just denotes multiplication.)

Comment: in the definition of $E$, is is $\forall \lambda$ or $\exists \lambda$ ?

Comment: $\forall\,\lambda>0$